# NASM instruction sequence

Tags: assembly, nasm

Learning from https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/05-bootsector-functions-strings, I've been trying to write my own boot sector.

I'm currently trying to print a given string.

These are my two files:

boot_main.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, hello
call print
jmp $

hello db 'HI', 0

%include "boot_print.asm"

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

boot_print.asm

```
print:
    pusha

start:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0
    je done

    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10

    add bx, 1
    jmp start

done:
    popa
    ret

print_nl:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10

    jmp done
```

Now this works perfectly and prints "HI" on to the screen. But if I move the instruction `hello db 'HI', 0` to the start. i.e

boot_main.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]

hello db 'HI', 0

mov bx, hello
call print
jmp $

%include "boot_print.asm"

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

This fails to print anything at all. I'm trying to understand the difference between the two. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assembler puts stuff in memory according to where you write it in your source file. If you put it right at the beginning, after the `org` directive, the `HI\0` string will be placed there, and the CPU will try to run it as if it was code (doing nonsensical stuff and possibly faulting).

In the original code, instead, the string is located after the `jmp $`, where it is safely stored in a location that isn't ever reached by the instruction pointer.

If you modify your code to make the CPU sidestep the string you'll see that it starts working again:

```
[org 0x7c00]
    jmp real_start
    hello db 'HI', 0
real_start:
    mov bx, hello
    call print
    jmp $
    %include "boot_print.asm"
    times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

Again, this becomes obvious if you think that `db` doesn't really do anything magic about strings, it just outputs arbitrary bytes in the output binary in the position where you write it. If you write them in the path of execution the CPU will run over them, if you tell the CPU to jump around them it will avoid them.

Comment: Your example with the sidestep was icing on the cake, beautiful, thanks! :)

Comment: @KarthikNayak: glad it helped! Interestingly, code that sidesteps data intermixed with it is actually used "in real life" when generating position-independent code, and/or when you have data that is small but that doesn't qualify for being an immediate, but can still benefit from being already in cache alongside the cold that uses it.

Comment: Off Topic, could you explain the joke in your profile?

Comment: ON Topic, interesting, any examples of such use cases?

Comment: On topic: I've seen it in x86_64 code that wanted to always load the same `double` (or 64 bit integer or pointer) into a register, although usually the data is put at the end of the function, if it's not too big; this stems from the fact that x86_64 doesn't have a way to specify 64-bit immediate values, so you have to always load them from memory. RIP addressing makes it easy to do this and still having position-independent code and keeping everything together in memory.

Comment: The alternative way would be loading the immediate value in two chunks, putting them together with or and shifts; that is routinely done for 32 bit immediates on some RISC architectures (where they have a fixed 32 bit instruction size, so a 32 bit immediate cannot possibly fit), but they usually make it less cumbersome than it would be on x86 - ARMv7 have the specialized `movw` and `movt` to load the bottom and top half of a register, PowerPC have a built-in shift in all ALU instructions, so in both cases it boils down to two instructions.